# Cloud Function for Firebase is not always triggered after a file is stored on Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am triggering a Cloud Function when a file is stored on Cloud Storage to either blur an image or create a thumbnail for the image. I am experiencing that the Cloud Function is not always triggered when the file updated on Cloud Storage. I don't see any errors on the Logs console. I just don't see any invocation of the Cloud Function in these instances. I am not sure what information can I provide in order to help in figuring out the problem. Below is how I am triggering the Cloud Function which is same as described in one of the samples of using Cloud Functions.

```
exports.processImage = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  const object = event.data

  // Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
  if (object.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    return Promise.resolve()
  }

  // Process image
  // Here I have code to either blur the image or resize the image based on some metadata on the image
})
```

Comment: You may want to contact Firebase support.  The product is still in beta and if the function is only firing some of the time then that points to a bigger issue.